# Internet Explorer; 2 quick click change checkbox state ounce but call onclick function twice

Tags: internet-explorer, checkbox, onclick, double-click, checked

I am having problems with Internet Explorer check-box. After reading and testing in many browser I found out that 2 quick click to check or unchecked a checkbox change the state of the box only 1 time (on the first click and the second click is kind of ignored) but execute the 'onclick' function twice.

I wanted to know if there is a clean workaround for this issue.

**MORE DETAILS :**

My 'onclick' function look for the state of the checkbox, if it is checked it adds a control; if it is unchecked it removes a control (work in every browser flawlessly). 
In IE if I double click the checkbox, the box is checked on the first click, the function adds a control (since the state is checked), on the second click the state is not changed (IE consider that both click were close enough to be a double click) but the function is executed a second time with the state unchanged.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Internet Explorer checkbox accepts double click but changing state only once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908000/why-internet-explorer-checkbox-accepts-double-click-but-changing-state-only-once)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found out what the problem was, the problem was me using a 'onclick' instead of a 'onchange'. Hope this will help someone.